# How to use namespaced-openvpn for VPN per application?

Tags: networking, 18.04, openvpn

This is probably a rather newbie-question, but...

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and I have a **VPN** which I want to use for a few applications. I checked out [`namespaced-openvpn`](https://github.com/slingamn/namespaced-openvpn) and it works! The caveat is, that I am not able to connect to this application locally (for management purposes).

**Is there a way to forward a certain port inside the VPN-tunnel to the localhost *without the VPN-tunnel using it for any other purposes and thus leaking too much information?***

***What I already am able to do:***

- run [`namespaced-openvpn`](https://github.com/slingamn/namespaced-openvpn)-script: `sudo ./namespaced-openvpn --namespace vpn --config /etc/openvpn/vpn-xxxxx.ovpn`
- execute application inside the network namespace: `sudo ip netns exec vpn application`

***What I want to achieve:***

- connect to the application started inside the VPN-tunnel (at e.g. port `1234`) from the real localhost (`enp3s0` ethernet adapter)
- forward this port in a way that enables me to access it from my other computers in my LAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. It seems this question is too complicated for someone to actually answer or perhaps it has been answered before and no one cared to reply.

Anyhow: I worked on it for another day and have figured that since I am only interested in exposing one port for the web interface of an application, I may as well use [`socat`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2012/07/socat-cheatsheet/). So I did.

After creating the namespaced-openvpn connection and starting the application inside that network namespace, I ran the following command in a dedicated terminal:

```bsh
sudo socat tcp-listen:PORT-TO-FORWARD-TO,fork,reuseaddr exec:'ip netns exec vpn socat STDIO tcp-connect\:127.0.0.1\:PORT-TO-LISTEN-TO',nofork
```

***Notes:***

- `PORT-TO-FORWARD-TO` is the port that I want the port to be forwarded to (in the root network namespace)
- `PORT-TO-LISTEN-TO` is the port of the application, which I want to expose into the root namespace
- `127.0.0.1` I had to use the actual localhost-IP (not `localhost` or a name, because it does not seem to get resolved properly)
- make sure to escape the double-point-character (`:`) inside the single-quotes
- I am not sure whether this causes DNS-leaks; from what I have checked it does not, but I cannot be certain since I do not know how to test it

***What's left to do:***

- automate all the commands in order to start the application and forward the port on startup: I do not need this currently, but if / when I find out how to do it, I shall add it here

Answer (score 2):

Many years late, but in case someone comes across this as I wish I did for the last couple of days or so.
Hope it helps someone.

First, here is namespaced-vpn which does like 90% of the work of getting everything running.
https://github.com/slingamn/namespaced-openvpn

And here is an answer to question almost exactly like this one that helped me alot even though I didn't understand what and why things were being done.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391193/how-to-forward-traffic-between-linux-network-namespaces

I will try to explain what I've come to understand after a lot of trial and error using the bits and pieces of info I've found in my searches.
The most relevant part for forwarding connections to your service (not from the PC the service is running on), I believe, is this (notice the exclamation mark after PREROUTING):

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING ! -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2`

Where, `10.0.0.0/24` represents the IP ranges that you DON'T WANT forwarded are assigned. 
 This is mostly to prevent a routing loop, where any services accessible by using `10.0.0.0/24` subnet gets routed back to itself.

 --dport 80 is to only forward packets seeking port 80 I.E a webserver connection.

 `10.0.0.2` is the veth interface that has been moved INSIDE the namespace your server is running.

 This makes it so that packets coming in, NOT from `10.0.0.0/24` subnet, that are seeking port 80 service get their destination IP translated to `10.0.0.2`. Example: `192.168.1.200:80` becomes `10.0.0.2:80` which is presumably the interface inside the namespace your server lives in.

I have multiple vpn tunnels up and running in multiple namespaces. If I don't add the PREROUTING rule to my iptables, I cannot access the resource from outside my PC on my LAN.

If you want it accessible from your own PC you have to add a rule like:
`iptables --table nat --append OUTPUT --destination 192.168.1.2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2` 
So, if you type into browser, on the pc the server is on, `192.168.1.2` to access your server, it gets routed to `10.0.0.2` instead.

I will try to explain a piece of my setup...

Example namespace: `ip netns add ns_example`

Create veth pair. One side will stay in root/normal namespace(I call this `host`), the other side will go to the namespace with VPN.
`ip link add dev ihost type veth peer name ivpn`

Move vpn side of the veth pair into target namespace:
`ip link set dev ivpn netns ns_example`

###### Assign ips to the veth pair you've created.

I use /32 because I only want to assign this exact IP and not a range. Otherwise, when I bring the devices UP, there are some routes automatically inserted in my `ip route` table and it messes up my routing for my other namespaces.

To assign to host side.
`ip addr add 10.0.0.1/32 dev ihost`

To assign to vpn side, which has been moved to the namespace, you must prefix command with..
`ip netns exec TARGET_NAMESPACE`

So, to assign ip to vpn side:
`ip netns exec ns_example ip addr add 10.0.0.2/32 dev ivpn`

###### Now bring interfaces up.

`ip link set dev ihost up`

`ip netns exec ns_example ip link set dev ivpn up`

Here I add routes and iptables to make traffic flow between them.
From root namespace, to get to VPN side(`10.0.0.2`), use interface ihost and rewrite source address to root namespace side(`10.0.0.1`).
`ip route add 10.0.0.2/32 dev ihost src 10.0.0.1`

Do exact same thing but from opposite perspective inside the VPN namespace.
`ip netns exec ns_example ip route add 10.0.0.1/32 dev ivpn src 10.0.0.2`

Now, I add the same operations to `iptables` which is separate from `ip route` but accomplish similar tasks.

Any packet going to `10.0.0.2` gets it's source address rewritten to `10.0.0.1`
`iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --destination 10.0.0.2/32 --jump SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1`

Exact same thing, but opposite perspective and inside namespace.
`ip netns exec ns_example iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --destination 10.0.0.1/32 --jump SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.2`

If I understand correctly, the source address rewrites are just to make sure the packet knows how to get back out of the namespace and vice versa.

Now, for example: to access a torrent webui in namespace on port 8080, I do this.
Any packet going to my LAN ip(Example: I type `192.168.1.2:8080` in browser). It will rewrite destination to the namespace my torrent client is running(Example: `10.0.0.2`).
`iptables --table nat --append OUTPUT --destination 192.168.1.2/32 --protocol tcp --match tcp --dport 8080 --jump DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2` 
This rule specifically only forwards port 8080 and this rule is for you to access the service ON THE PC the service is running on. Any other PC on network accessing `192.168.1.2:8080` needs the PREROUTING rule I mentioned at the top of answer(just change --dport 80 to --dport 8080 or whatever port/protocol you need).

For people who use this method and namespaced-vpn.py script. You may have issues if you ever have to reset your vpn. Namespaced vpn throws an exception when it detects interfaces inside your target namespace other than the `lo` loopback interface.
Here is the part that throws exceptions for me when I use namespaced-vpn.py when my target namespace already exists and it has my veth pairs.

```
if os.path.exists(os.path.join('/var/run/netns', namespace)):
        adapters = _adapter_names(namespace)
        if adapters != [b'lo']:
            LOG.error('Namespace %s already has adapters %s, exiting.' % (namespace, adapters))
            raise Exception
```

Here is an example modification I've used.

```
allowed_adapters = [b'lo', b'ivpn']
if os.path.exists(os.path.join('/var/run/netns', namespace)):
     adapters = _adapter_names(namespace)
     # Iterate and ensure all are in allowed list
     for a in adapters:
         if not a.split(b'@')[0] in allowed_adapters:
            LOG.error('Namespace %s has non-whitelisted adapters %s, exiting.' % (namespace, adapters))
            raise Exception
```

Just make sure to add call like this for each interface you expect to already exist at the bottom of `def setup_namespace(namespace)` function. replace LO with name of device

```
subprocess.check_call(_enter_namespace_cmd(namespace) + [IP_CMD, 'link', 'set', 'LO', 'up'])
```

Example:

```
subprocess.check_call(_enter_namespace_cmd(namespace) + [IP_CMD, 'link', 'set', 'ivpn', 'up'])
```

For people who run a bittorrent client attached to vpn interface, you may run into issue of your client stalling connections randomly for whatever reason. Such as, you wake up in morning to see all your beautiful downloads were frozen 10 minutes after you left.
I believe this issue is because of vpn software I.E openvpn, reconnecting to the vpn provider for whatever reason (error, ping-restart, etc) and being assigned a new IP address. The vpn interface might have to be taken offline for a split second to reset the configuration and this glitches the client(qBittorrent does this for sure). A "fix" I've started looking into is to write a script that detects when vpn interface receives a new IP address or is taken offline for whatever reason. The script should gracefully(important: graceful to avoid corrupting something/filesystem error) exit the torrent client and then restart it. I don't have a working script yet, but that seems to be a decent vector for solving this issue.